# RenderRequest to call jsp in liferay6

Tags: jsp, liferay

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

**The jsp:**

```
<a href="<portlet:renderURL >
<portlet:param name="page" value="/view_dettaglio.jsp"/>
<portlet:param name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt(1)%=>"/>
</portlet:renderURL>"><%=rs.getInt(1)%></a>
```

**Method in the class:**

```
@Override
public void doView(final RenderRequest renderRequest, final RenderResponse renderResponse) throws PortletException, IOException {
  String page = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "page");
 String id = ParamUtil.getInteger(renderRequest, "id");
  renderRequest.setAttribute("id",id.toString());   
  this.include(page, renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does ***isn't working*** mean? Do U see any errors? or when you refresh the page with this portlet you don't see the JSP properly? Or the method `doView` is not called? and I assume the configuration of the portlet is done correctly.

Comment: And is it OK to use double quotes inside double quotes or should they be escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the `portlet` namespace?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
```

It is best to store the render URL in a separate variable before using it, so you don't have a clash in the quoting:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="renderUrl">
    <portlet:param name="page" value="/view_dettaglio.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt(1)%>"/>
</portlet:renderUrl>

<a href="<%=renderUrl%>"><%=rs.getInt(1)%></a>
```

You also had an error in the value of the `id` parameter: the closing bracket contained an additional equal sign, so it said `%=>` instead of `%>`. This is probably the real cause of the problem.